# Pycharm is not showing the project view or editor of a project

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm having a bit of trouble with Pycharm. I tried opening a project with it, one that I know has files and folders in it, but for some reason, the project view and the editor is not visible at all. I checked one of the modules, and there is code in it, so I don't know why I can't get these things to show properly.

Comment: Look for something similar to this: Windows->Reset {windows or something else}

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I can't find anything like that.

Comment: Sry for late reply, because I don't have PyCharm installed on my machine, I was looking in internet for a solution, I founded this page take a look at the bottom of it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html  , It is weritten: "At a later time, you can return to the saved workspace layout by choosing Window | Restore Default Layout" maybe you can restore the default windows buy doing so, I hope that it will help you :)

Answer (score 2):

View, Tool Windows, Project

All of these can be accessed by alt + number keys.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So apparently all I needed to do was close Pycharm and start it up again.

Comment: Did you find && try "Window --> Restore Default Layout"?